Getting aspect-ratio of shapely rectangle
This snippet calculates an aspect ratio of a rectangle not constrained to be parallel to the coordinate axes:
from shapely import *

rect = oriented_envelope(LineString([(1, 1), (5, 1), (10, 10)]))
p0 = get_point(rect.exterior, 0)
p1 = get_point(rect.exterior, 1)
p2 = get_point(rect.exterior, 2)
d0 = distance(p0, p1)
d1 = distance(p1, p2)
aspect = min(d0, d1)/max(d0, d1)
print(f'{rect:.1f}  {aspect:.2f}')

Output:
POLYGON ((3.0 -1.0, 12.0 8.0, 10.0 10.0, 1.0 1.0, 3.0 -1.0))  0.22

Is there a simpler way to accomplish it?

Doesn't rect have a width and height method?

@IanTurton rect is a Polygon, which doesn't have width property.

It depends on what you want to accomplish. I don't know a simpler algorithm to calculate it. If you want to improve performance, there are some options that should be faster if you want to calculate this for many geometries.

@Pieter By simpler, I meant making better use of Shapely API, e.g. getting polygon sides directly. I have very little experience with Shapely and wanted to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.
